# If $p$ is unramified in every subfield of $K$, does it mean $p$ is unramified in $K$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am wondering if $p$ being unramified in every subfield of $K$ means $p$ is unramified in $K$.

Any hints?

Comment: This is not true, a very easy counterexample is any quadratic number field (having only one subfield: $\Bbb{Q}$).

Comment: @Crostul What if we don't count the trivial subfield then?

Comment: A non-trivial example is $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt5}2})$. $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$ is its only non trivial subfield. Nevertheless, $2$ ramifies in $K$.